# MySQL Can I nest SELECT LEFT inside a SELECT statement?

Tags: mysql

I am playing around with a query that returns the first two names from a column. I do this by picking up everything around the first occurrence of `,` which is the separator for the names.
Here is a [Functioning version](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a46406/2) @ SQL Fiddle.

The table looks similar to this:

```
| Director |                  CriteriaData                  |
|||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||
| Director1|NameA Surname A, NameB SurnameB, NameC SurnameC |
| Director2|NameA Surname A, NameB SurnameB, NameC SurnameC |
| Director3|NameA Surname A, NameB SurnameB, NameC SurnameC |
```

and the functioning query is:

```
SELECT LEFT(CriteriaData, LEN(CriteriaData) - CHARINDEX(', ', CriteriaData)) AS "2 names"
FROM Table1
WHERE  CriteriaData  LIKE '%, %'
```

What I am trying to achieve, is to have two result columns. One called `Director` and the other one being the results of the query above, called `2 names` 
This is my failed attempt: [Test version](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a46406/11), where I have tried to nest the original query inside a new query. It looks like this:

```
SELECT 

Director, 
(LEFT(CriteriaData, LEN(CriteriaData) - CHARINDEX(', ', CriteriaData))
FROM Table1
WHERE  CriteriaData  LIKE '%, %')AS "2 names"

FROM Table1
WHERE Director = 'Director3'
```

In the result table I want to see

```
|Director |           2 Names              |
||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||
|Director3| NameA Surname A, NameB SurnameB|
```

I hope that this makes any sense and that what I am trying to achieve is doable. Thank you very much for reading. I am looking forward to your suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe I'm getting the question wrong, but is this what you're looking for?

```
SELECT 
CriteriaData,
LEFT(CriteriaData, LEN(CriteriaData) - CHARINDEX(', ', CriteriaData))  AS "2 names"
FROM Table1
WHERE  CriteriaData  LIKE '%, %'
AND Director = 'Director3'
```

Comment: No, you got it absolutely right. So the problem was that I was sticking the second `select` in there. I thought it has to be there in front of the `left`. Thank you so much.

Comment: Actually it isn't. I just realized it has to work a bit different. Is there any way to nest the whole select statement in the initial select? I mean along with the `FROM` and `WHERE`? The reason for that is that the actual `WHERE` for the main select will be different.

Comment: I have updated my question with more details and have also updated the fiddles.